# Is there a Java EE way to change user?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Assume the follwing method:

```
Test getTest() 
{ 
  Properties props = new Properties(); 
  props.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "OtherUser"); 
  props.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "OtherPassword"); 
  InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props); 
  return (TestHome)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ic.lookup("ejb/Test"), 
           TestHome.class).create(); 
}
```

If this method (in an EJB) is called from a client using user "MyUser" I'd like it to return an EJB with a different caller principal. Calls to Test made by the client would then be noted as being from "OtherUser". i.e. I have programmactially changed a client's caller principal for a given EJB.

However, I find no text on this in the Java EE specs and although it works on our current Java EE app-server (Sybase EAS 4.1), I'd like to ask you if this is a Java EE standard approach or not.

Answer (score 1):

A *standard* way of handling login/logoff is JAAS. I don't know if it's fair to say that it is *the* standard, but it's supported by the Java EE servers I've worked with so far (JBoss, Websphere), and apparently also by Sybase EAS.

JBoss, for instance, comes with several predefined login modules for Database and LDAP and whatnot, that you just have to declaratively configure for your application. However, you are also completely free to write your own login module by implementing the respective interface (`javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule`).

Take a look at [the JAAS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html).

About your code snippet: I don't know if that'll work on other app servers. This is EJB 1.1, and thus really, really old stuff. You should definitely look at EJB 3.1 and consider modernizing your application anyway.

Comment: In Java EE JAAS in is not the overall security framework that you may think it is. The login modules in JBoss for instance are only based on JAAS. The official API to do login/logoff with in Java EE is JASPIC. This is a pretty good article from one of the guys involved with many security APIs in Java EE: http://java.sys-con.com/node/1002315

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right this should link a username to an EJB across more than one methodcall, which in my opinion is a state. I guess the standard for this would be to create a Stateful SessionBean with a `setUser(String name)` method. In a stateless bean you would have to pass the userName (or properties object) on each methodcall.